# Right syntax for WHERE IN in Joomla Jdatabase

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

I have this query

```
SELECT * 
  FROM #__k2_items 
 WHERE catid IN ('4,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22') 
   AND published='1'
```

But it's not working, it is just retrieving items from catid 4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove the quotes (`'`) unless catid is a string and then put them around each number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
SELECT * 
FROM #__k2_items 
WHERE catid IN (4,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22)
  AND published=1
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM #__k2_items 
WHERE catid IN ('4','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22')
  AND published='1'
```